# AbstractMethodError when creating custom Solr Query in Spring Data Solr 1.5.4

Tags: java, solr, spring-data, solr4, spring-data-solr

I am using Spring Boot 1.4, Spring Data JPA 1.10.2, Spring Data Solr 1.5.4 and Solr 4.10.4 in my project. The communication between my program and Solr works fine so far. I can `save()` and `findAll()`using the methods provided by the `SolrCrudRepository`.

The problem occurs when I try to add new Querys to the Repository. I tried using all three available methods of doing this (named querys, query annotation and method name) but all result in the same error when starting the webapp:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mySolrController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mySolrService': Error creating bean with name 'mySolrService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySolrRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySolrService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySolrRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
at com.my.project.BackupApplication.main(BackupApplication.java:22)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySolrService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySolrRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
... 19 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySolrRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
... 31 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SolrRepositoryFactoryBean.java:91)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 43 common frames omitted
```

My Respository looks as follows:

```
package com.my.project.repository.solr;

import com.my.project.mapping.SolrEntry;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.SolrCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface MySolrRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<SolrEntry, String> {
    @Query(value = "channel:*?0*")
    List<SolrEntry> findByChannel(String channel);
}
```

And the mapping class for the SolrDocuments looks like this:

```
package com.my.project.mapping;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import java.util.UUID;

public class SolrEntry {

    @Id
    @Field
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String message;

    @Field
    private String channel;

    @Field
    private String user;

    @Field
    private String timestamp;

    public SolrEntry(String channel, String user, String message, String timestamp) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.channel = channel;
        this.user = user;
        this.message = message;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    //Getter and Setter omitted
}
```

The `SolrContext`is created like this:

```
package com.my.project.config;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrOperations;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.EnableSolrRepositories;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.project.repository.solr", multicoreSupport = true)
public class SolrContext {

    static final String SOLR_HOST = "solr.host";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public SolrServer solrServer() {
        return new HttpSolrServer(environment.getRequiredProperty(SOLR_HOST));
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrOperations solrTemplate() {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrServer());
    }
}
```

I followed this [manual](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-query-methods/) in addition to the official [Spring Data Solr Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#solr.repositories) for configuring this and didn't find a solution while googling the issue.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I figured it out. Seems to be a problem with Spring Boot 1.4 and Spring Data Solr 1.5.4. I downgraded to Spring Boot 1.3.7 and it worked immediatly.